# Async SQL query execution - Task.WaitAll(tasks) never completes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have an app to move data from a MS SQL server into a MySQL server using async query execution; the data moves fine but Task.WaitAll(tasks) call in the RunAllTasks() method never completes.

The async tasks all follow the pattern of PumpLocsAsync() where the call to MS SQL is invoked asynchronously via BeginExecuteReader; when the reader returns with results, then MySQL inserts normally.

..

```
async Task PumpLocsAsync()
{
     using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnStr))
     using (var cn = new MySqlConnection(MysqlConnStr))
     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
     {
          cmd.Connection = conn;
          cmd.CommandText = "SELECT HERE";

          conn.Open();
          var handle = cmd.BeginExecuteReader();
          await Task.Factory.FromAsync(handle, (ar) =>
          {
               var rdr = cmd.EndExecuteReader(ar);
               var qry = @"INSERT HERE";

               cn.Open();
               using (var cmdm = new MySqlCommand(qry, cn))
               {
                   cmdm.CommandTimeout = MysqlCmdtimeout;
                   <PARAM SETUP HERE>
                   <COLUMN MAPPING HERE>

                   while (RetryUtility.RetryMethod<bool>(() => rdr.Read(), 3, 1000))
                   {
                       <LOADING PARAMS WITH BITS HERE>
                       RetryUtility.RetryAction(() => cmdm.ExecuteNonQuery(), 3, 1000);
                   }
               }
               Console.WriteLine("Finished Locs!");
               cn.Close();
          });
          conn.Close();
    }
}


...

        void RunAllTasks()
        {
            Task[] tasks = { PumpLocsAsync(), PumpPicsAsync() };

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
                Console.WriteLine("Finished with all tasks...");
                foreach (var task in tasks)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Status: {1}", task.Id, task.Status);
                }
            }

....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstood how to call `Task.Factory.FromAsync()`, you pass to it the result of the `BeginXxx` method and a delegate to the `EndXxx` method:

```
var rdr = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
    cmd.BeginExecuteReader,
    (Func<IAsyncResult, SqlDataReader>)cmd.EndExecuteReader,
    null);
```

If you want to do something after the operation completes, simply put it below this line, `await` will make sure it executes at the right time.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

    var rdr = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(cmd.BeginExecuteReader()
    , (Func<IAsyncResult, SqlDataReader>)cmd.EndExecuteReader);

Comment: Whenever possible, I recommend passing a delegate to the `Begin*` method instead of the result of the `Begin*` method. `FromAsync` is more efficient if it can wrap the entire Begin/End transaction into a `Task`. If it only has an `IAsyncResult`, then it has to call `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` (and you can only have 64 of those in an app domain) on the `AsyncWaitHandle` (which is usually lazy-created). OTOH, if it has both delegates, then it can provide its own `AsyncCallback` to the `Begin*` method, and the `TaskCompletionSource` wrapper is quite simple.

Comment: Followup: Stephen Toub has a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/06/10264610.aspx) on why the delegate version is preferred.

Comment: I must be missing something because while the code above compiles, execution never gets past it. Shouldn't I just be able to use the rdr on the next line or does the 2nd param return need more wiring? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to use `rdr` on the line, as if it was synchronous code. I have no idea where your problem could be.

Comment: I actually tried it out and [it works for me](https://gist.github.com/2472782). The only thing I can think of that could be wrong is if the code is in a GUI application. Because if that was the case, then the way you're using `WaitAll()` would cause a deadlock.

Comment: That's probably it - using it in a WinForms app.  How should I wait on task completion in a GUI app?  Thanks

Comment: You should use `await` again. In your case, `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` and make the method into `async Task RunAllTasks()`.

Comment: OK, it works now after I rewrote it as a console application; thanks for all the helpful comments.  I turned the project into a template and put it on https://github.com/dr3x/DataPumpAsync